# Use of LOCALE_ILANGUAGE constant can cause GetLocaleInfo to return an invalid locale identifier?

Tags: windows, winapi

According to the MS documentation for [LOCALE_ILANGUAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373781(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **Windows Vista and later:** Use of this constant can cause [GetLocaleInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318101(v=vs.85).aspx) to return an invalid locale identifier. Your application should use the [LOCALE_SNAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373858(v=vs.85).aspx) constant when calling this function.

The MS documentation for [GetLocaleInfo function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318101(v=vs.85).aspx) states:

> **Note**  For interoperability reasons, the application should prefer the [GetLocaleInfoEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318103(v=vs.85).aspx) function to **GetLocaleInfo** because Microsoft is migrating toward the use of locale names instead of locale identifiers for new locales. Any application that runs only on Windows Vista and later should use [GetLocaleInfoEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318103(v=vs.85).aspx).

The MS documentation for [GetLocaleInfoEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318103(v=vs.85).aspx) states:

> Starting with Windows Vista, your applications should not use [LOCALE_ILANGUAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373781(v=vs.85).aspx) in the *LCType* parameter to avoid failure or retrieval of unexpected data. Instead, it is recommended for your applications to call **GetLocaleInfoEx**.

**Now my question:**

Since the use of **LOCALE_ILANGUAGE** appears to becoming deprecated, how is one supposed to specify the **CF_LOCALE** for the clipboard?  MS documentation for [Standard Clipboard Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **CF_LOCALE** 16
>
> ---
>
> The data is a handle to the locale identifier associated with text in the clipboard. When you close the clipboard, if it contains **CF_TEXT** data but no **CF_LOCALE** data, the system automatically sets the **CF_LOCALE** format to the current input language. You can use the **CF_LOCALE** format to associate a different locale with the clipboard text.
>
> An application that pastes text from the clipboard can retrieve this format to determine which character set was used to generate the text.
>
> Note that the clipboard does not support plain text in multiple character sets. To achieve this, use a formatted text data type such as RTF instead.
>
> The system uses the code page associated with **CF_LOCALE** to implicitly convert from **CF_TEXT** to **CF_UNICODETEXT**. Therefore, the correct code page table is used for the conversion.

Or is it also assumed that nobody is going to use MBCS anymore?  If this is the case, what sort of timeline are we talking about for complete deprecation?

I ask this because I'm working on a legacy application and need to understand to tell my superiors.

Comment: Using CF_TEXT or CF_OEMTEXT stopped making sense 24 years ago. Relying on LCID stopped making sense 11 years ago.  Since 24 > 11, you can't have a real problem by 13, locales that don't have an LCID also don't have a ANSI or OEM code page.  If you don't have a code page then 8-bit encoded text is just gibberish to a program that does use Unicode.  They all do.  Ultimately it is Darwin that sorts this out, companies that sell MBCS programs just don't make a sale in locations where that works poorly.

Comment: What they likely mean but avoiding LOCALE_ILANGUAGE is that because of transition to string representation not every locale will return reliable LCID anymore. The reason for that could be internal transition to locale names, so they do LCID -> name translation, and call Ex functions internally, However it's very unlikely they will break it on purpose for locales that worked before Vista.

Comment: Regarding MBCS - they are not going away obviously, a lot of stuff depends on that, and MS cares about backward compatibility more than anyone.

Comment: @HansPassant, what do you mean by `Since 24 > 11, you can't have a real problem by 13`?